# How do I remove "kg" and "m" from my csv data?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I just want to have values. I'm looking to remove the 'm' and 'kg' from the columns. 
Here is my code so far, it works great. But the only problem is the 'm' and 'kg. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
import requests
import time
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

#Main function
def getContent(link):
    #Open Browser
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    #Go to link
    browser.get(link)

    #Pause
    time.sleep(3)

    #Source
    html = browser.page_source

    #Soup activate
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

    #Find table
    table = soup.find_all('table')
    table2 = table[1]

    #Save in csv
    with open('averageheight.csv','w',newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(('Country','Average Height Male','Average Weight Male','Average BMI Male','Average Height Female','Average Weight Female','Average BMI Female'))
        for tr in table2('tr')[1:]:
            row = [(t.get_text(strip=True)).encode('utf-8') for t in tr(['td','th'])]
            writer.writerow(row)

    #Close browser
    browser.close()
    browser.quit()

#Links
getContent('https://www.worlddata.info/average-bodyheight.php')
```

Heres the current output

```
Country,Average Height Male,Average Weight Male,Average BMI Male,Average Height Female,Average Weight Female,Average BMI Female
b'Netherlands',b'',b'1.83 m',b'87.4 kg',b'26.1',b'',b'1.69 m',b'72.3 kg',b'25.3'
```

The second, third, forth and fifth column the extra 'm' and 'kg'. Those are the ones I'm trying to replace. But no luck yet.

Comment: Need examples of the csv data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the web page and your output data, there is always a space between the number and 'kg' or 'm'. In this case a simple split about a space might do the trick.

Replace the assignment to `row` with the following:

`row = [(t.get_text(strip=True)).split(" ")[0].encode('utf-8') for t in tr(['td','th'])]`

Here we are splitting each tag text value about the space character and keeping only the first value.

Answer (score 1):

> you had some best practice issues with your code

```
import requests
import time , os
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

#Main function
def getContent(link):

    #Go to link
    browser.get(link)

    #Pause
    time.sleep(3)

    #Source
    html = browser.page_source

    #Soup activate
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

    #Find table
    table_rows = soup.select('table[id="avgsizes"] tbody tr')
    if table_rows:       
        for tr in table_rows[1:]:
            #'td', class_=lambda x: x != 'blank') to skip blank tds
            row = [(t.get_text(strip=True)).replace(' kg','').replace(' m','').encode('utf-8') for t in tr.find_all('td', class_=lambda x: x != 'blank')]
            SaveAsCsv(row)


def SaveAsCsv(list_of_rows):
    try:
        with open('averageheight.csv', mode='a',  newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            csv.writer(outfile).writerow(list_of_rows)
    except PermissionError:
        print("Please make sure averageheight.csv is closed\n")

if os.path.isfile('averageheight.csv') and os.access('averageheight.csv', os.R_OK):
    print("File averageheight.csv Already exists \n")
else:
    SaveAsCsv([ 'Country','Average Height Male','Average Weight Male','Average BMI Male','Average Height Female','Average Weight Female','Average BMI Female'])


#Open Browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
try:
    getContent('https://www.worlddata.info/average-bodyheight.php')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    #Close browser
    browser.close()
```

Output:
[image]